# Vim multiple windows / hide

Tags: vim

If I had x or more windows open in a VIM session and I wanted to quickly hide all but the active one for a moment then return the windows to the layout I had them int how would I do it?

Comment: The zoomwin plugin does this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Vim 7 and later, you can use a “tab page” for this (i.e. “GUI-style” tab). You can use the [`:tab`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tabpage.txt.html#%3Atab) command with either [`:split`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Asplit) or [`:sbuffer`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Asbuffer):

```
:tab split
:tab sp      " shorter version

:tab sbuffer
:tab sb      " shorter version
```

Both `split` and `sbuffer` do nearly the same thing when used without additional arguments (split the current buffer). You will probably want to use `split` if you anticipate wanting to load some (possibly not-already loaded) pathname (`split path/to/some/file`; although you could just use [`:tabe`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tabpage.txt.html#%3Atabedit) instead since this is in the context of opening a new tab); `sbuffer` makes it easier to switch to an existing buffer (`sb {bufnum}` or `sb {bufname}`).

Once you have your new tab open, you can use `gT` and `gt` to switch between the resulting tabs (or the GUI controls if you are using a GUI version of Vim). When you are finished with your single-window tab, just `:q` to close the window (and thus the tab) and return to your original tab (with its original window layout), or use `:tabclose` (`:tabc`), or switch back to your original tab and use `:tabonly` (`:tabo`).

Comment: I give this an upvote because the point is to consider a tab as something "disposable."  Something you can open up, have your way with, then throw out when you're done.  I've been putting tabs on a pedestal for too long.

Answer (score 12):

I use CTRL-W _ to horizontally "push" the other windows out of the way making the current window the expand to the largest available area. Use CTRL-W | to do the same vertically. I'm sure there's probably a way to do both at once, but I haven't noticed or looked for it. Look in :help CTRL-W

To restore them do CTRL-W =. One caveat though is they aren't restored to their original configuration. CTRL-W = actually re-calculates the best fit for all the windows in the screen.

Comment: Check for being a neat hack to implement.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, there is no way to simply switch between two different window layouts, but you can hide all other windows by issuing the command `:only` (or `:on`). See the [Vim help for this command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#%3aonly).

Comment: Its not possible go back to the previous layout with this. Chris Johnsen's answer lets us do that as well.